# Fatter arrowheads in xy-pic

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I am formatting some diagrams using arrows in xy-pic.  The "standard" arrow head that xy-pic produces with the command `\ar` is quite different (much smaller, thinner) than that produced by using the command `\to` (outside of the xy-pic environment).  I like the fatter arrowhead much better.  How can I tell xy-pic that this is what I want??

The difference in output can be seen by compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[X\to Y\]

\[
\xymatrix{X\ar[r] & Y}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\SelectTips{cm}{12}` just after the `\usepackage[all]{xy}` for computer modern tips.

Or you could simply say `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` (thanks to Phil Hirschorn).

Comment: Equivalently, say `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}`